# Doing a re.findall with pcre library

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to get an array of all regex matches. For example, something like this:

```
PATTERN: (\d+)[a-z]+
STRING:  123asd
RESULT:  ["123asd", "123"]
            ^         ^
           full      capture group 1
```

Additionally, if there are multiple matches, it should continue matching, for example:

```
123asd   123asd   
[ ["123asd", "123"],   ["123asd", "123"] ]
       ^                      ^            
      match 1                match 2
```

Here is what I came up with, where I try and create functions to do each of the items (though I haven't yet added a `fetch_all()` function):

```
// pcretest.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8
#include <pcre2.h>

pcre2_code* pcre_compile_pattern(PCRE2_SPTR pattern, uint32_t options)
{
    PCRE2_SIZE error_offset;
    int error_number;

    pcre2_code *re_compiled = pcre2_compile(pattern, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, options, &error_number, &error_offset, NULL);
    if (re_compiled == NULL) {
        PCRE2_UCHAR buffer[256];
        pcre2_get_error_message(error_number, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Error: Compiling of pattern '%s' failed at offset %d: %s\n", pattern, (int)error_offset, buffer);
    }
    return re_compiled;
}

struct match_obj {
    int size;
    char** matches;
};

// will return the offset of the full-match (or an error-code), and populate the struct match_obj
int get_next_match(pcre2_code *re_compiled, PCRE2_SPTR8 string, struct match_obj *matches, int max_matches)
{
    #define MAX_MATCHES_EXCEEDED (-99)

    pcre2_match_data    *match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(re_compiled, NULL);
    int                 return_code = pcre2_match(re_compiled, string, strlen((char*)string), 0, 0, match_data, NULL);

    // Error codes: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2/src/pcre2.h.html#313
    if (return_code < 0) {
        PCRE2_UCHAR buffer[256];
        pcre2_get_error_message(return_code, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (return_code != PCRE2_ERROR_NOMATCH) 
            printf("Error trying to match against  '%s': %s\n", string, buffer);
        return return_code;
    }

    // Make sure no buffer overflow
    if (return_code > max_matches) {
        printf("Input buffer is too small.\n");
        return MAX_MATCHES_EXCEEDED;
    }

    PCRE2_SIZE *offset_vector = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer(match_data);

    matches->size = return_code;
    for (int i=0; i < return_code; i++)
    {
        PCRE2_SPTR substring_start = string + offset_vector[2*i];
        size_t substring_length = offset_vector[2*i+1] - offset_vector[2*i];
        char* string = malloc(sizeof *string * substring_length);
        strncpy(string, (const char*) substring_start, substring_length);
        matches->matches[i] = string;
    }

    // (start, end) of the full match is the zero'th entry
    int end_position = offset_vector[1];
    return end_position;


}
int main(void)
{

    PCRE2_SPTR8 pattern = (const unsigned char*) "he[al](lo)";
    PCRE2_SPTR8 string =  (const unsigned char*) "add ello a healo b hello c";

    // 1. Compile the pattern
    /* uint32_t re_options=0; */
    pcre2_code *re_compiled = pcre_compile_pattern(pattern, 0); 

    // 2. grab matches until expired
    #define MAX_MATCH_COMPONENTS 10
    #define MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES 10
    struct match_obj all_matches[MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES];

    int advance_by, total_matches=0;
    for (; total_matches < MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES; total_matches++) {
        struct match_obj *match_ptr = &all_matches[total_matches];
        match_ptr->matches = malloc(sizeof (char*) * MAX_MATCH_COMPONENTS);
        advance_by = get_next_match(re_compiled, string, match_ptr, MAX_MATCH_COMPONENTS);
        if (advance_by < 0) break;
        string += advance_by;
    }

    // 3. Display them (or do whatever we want with them)
    for (int match_num=0; match_num < total_matches; match_num++) {
        struct match_obj match = all_matches[match_num];
        for (int i=0; i<match.size; i++) printf("Match %d.%d: %s\n", match_num, i, match.matches[i]);
    }

    // 4. Free the allocations - array of string-pointers here, created-strings in get_next_match()
    for (int match_num=0; match_num < total_matches; match_num++) {
        for (int i=0; i < all_matches[match_num].size; i++)
            free(all_matches[match_num].matches[i]); // free the string
        free(all_matches[match_num].matches); // and the array of string pointers
    }

}
```

If helpful, here is the code on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/Bs1zV_u5k). Note, however, I wasn't able to compile with extra compiler flags to work with `#include <pcre2.h>`.

Here are a few specific questions about this:

1. Figuring out allocations are hard! Does the above look like a sensible approach? I couldn't figure out which function should do what. My first thought was to do everything 'on the stack' in `main` but then the string-pointer array started acting up and so I moved to `malloc`'s in main. Is there something like a good rule of thumb for where to do mallocs or how to split them up?
2. Does the data structure look up for returning the matches? I thought an array-of-char* 's would work, though I ended up creating a struct as there were some other things I needed to keep track of (how far it advances, what the matches are, how many matches there are -- though this last item is I think always the same if it's using the same pattern).

Comment: For reviewers: [related](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/259267/52915)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks generally good, and compiles almost cleanly.

The "almost" is because we return `int` from `get_next_match`, but try to shoehorn negative error numbers and positive `size_t` into it.  I'd at least change to return `long long`; it's probably better to return the length separately from the status.

---

We fail to free the `pcre2_code` and `pcre2_match_data` objects that we get from the PCRE library.

---

We fail to check the return value where we use `malloc()`.  Not doing so risks Undefined Behaviour when we dereference it.  Easily fixed:

```
        char* string = malloc(substring_length); /* sizeof (char) is necessarily 1 */
        if (!string) {
            return PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY;
        }
```

```
        match_ptr->matches = malloc(sizeof *match_ptr->matches * MAX_MATCH_COMPONENTS);
        if (!match_ptr->matches) {
            fprintf(stderr, strerror(ENOMEM));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
```

(We'll need to include `<stdlib.h>` to get a definition of `EXIT_FAILURE`)

---

Really, we should clean up properly even if we fail.  This will make it easier to re-use this code in a program that can't just exit in this case.  As you say, memory management is hard in C!

It's easiest if we define functions to initialise and release our structures:

---

The other problem we have with memory handling is here:

> ```
>    strncpy(string, (const char*) substring_start, substring_length);
> ```

Do you see what's missing there?  If not, then run Valgrind again, and look what happens when we print it.  We've copied the strings characters, but haven't provided a terminating `\0`, leading to more UB.

```
        char* string = malloc(substring_length + 1);
        if (!string) {
            return PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY;
        }
        memcpy(string, substring_start, substring_length);
        string[substring_length + 1] = '\0';
```

---

I don't like this macro definition buried halfway through a function:

> ```
>    #define MAX_MATCHES_EXCEEDED (-99)
> ```

Instead of a macro, define an integer at global scope:

```
static const int MAX_MATCHES_EXCEEDED = -99;
```

It's probably better to just allocate the size of results we need, in `get_next_match()` where the number is known, instead of having a fixed limit here.

---

The URL in comment is dead (404).

---

It's confusing to have a local variable `string` that shadows the function argument `string` in `get_next_match`.

---

## Modified code

This compiles without warnings using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wconversion  -Wstrict-prototypes`, and runs clean under Valgrind.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8
#include <pcre2.h>

struct match_obj {
    int count;
    char** matches;
};

static void match_obj_init(struct match_obj *p)
{
    p->count = 0;
    p->matches = NULL;
}

static void match_obj_free(struct match_obj *p)
{
    if (p) {
        for (int i = 0;  i < p->count;  ++i) {
            free(p->matches[i]);
        }
        free(p->matches);
    }
}

pcre2_code* pcre_compile_pattern(PCRE2_SPTR pattern, uint32_t options)
{
    PCRE2_SIZE error_offset;
    int error_number;

    pcre2_code *re_compiled = pcre2_compile(pattern, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, options, &error_number, &error_offset, NULL);
    if (re_compiled == NULL) {
        PCRE2_UCHAR buffer[256];
        pcre2_get_error_message(error_number, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Compiling of pattern '%s' failed at offset %zd: %s\n", pattern, error_offset, buffer);
    }
    return re_compiled;
}

// will return the offset of the full-match (or an error-code), and populate the struct match_obj
int get_next_match(pcre2_code *re_compiled, PCRE2_SPTR8 string,
                   struct match_obj *matches, size_t *advance)
{
    pcre2_match_data    *match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(re_compiled, NULL);
    int                 return_code = pcre2_match(re_compiled, string, strlen((char*)string), 0, 0, match_data, NULL);

    // Error codes: https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/include/pcre2.h.html#313
    if (return_code == PCRE2_ERROR_NOMATCH) {
        /* normal */
        free(match_data);
        return 0;
    }
    if (return_code < 0) {
        free(match_data);
        return return_code;
    }

    PCRE2_SIZE *offset_vector = pcre2_get_ovector_pointer(match_data);

    matches->matches = malloc(sizeof *matches->matches * (size_t)return_code);
    matches->count = return_code;
    if (!matches->matches) {
        free(match_data);
        return PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY;
    }
    for (int i = 0;  i < matches->count;  ++i) {
        matches->matches[i] = NULL;
    }

    for (int i = 0;  i < return_code;  ++i)
    {
        PCRE2_SPTR substring_start = string + offset_vector[2*i];
        size_t substring_length = offset_vector[2*i+1] - offset_vector[2*i];
        char *const s = malloc(substring_length + 1);
        if (!s) {
            free(match_data);
            return PCRE2_ERROR_NOMEMORY;
        }
        memcpy(s, substring_start, substring_length);
        s[substring_length] = '\0';
        matches->matches[i] = s;
    }

    // (start, end) of the full match is the zero'th entry
    *advance = offset_vector[1];
    pcre2_match_data_free(match_data);
    return 0;
}

#define MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES 10

int main(void)
{

    PCRE2_SPTR8 pattern = (const unsigned char*) "he[al](lo)";
    PCRE2_SPTR8 string =  (const unsigned char*) "add ello a healo b hello c";

    // 1. Compile the pattern
    /* uint32_t re_options=0; */
    pcre2_code *re_compiled = pcre_compile_pattern(pattern, 0);
    if (!re_compiled) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // 2. grab matches until expired
    struct match_obj all_matches[MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES];
    for (int i = 0;  i < MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES;  ++i) {
        match_obj_init(all_matches + i);
    }

    int total_matches=0;
    for (; total_matches < MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES;  ++total_matches) {
        struct match_obj *match_ptr = &all_matches[total_matches];

        size_t advance_by;
        int errcode = get_next_match(re_compiled, string, match_ptr, &advance_by);
        if (errcode) {
            PCRE2_UCHAR buffer[256];
            pcre2_get_error_message(errcode, buffer, sizeof buffer);
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Search failed: %s\n", buffer);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        string += advance_by;
    }

    pcre2_code_free(re_compiled);

    // 3. Display them (or do whatever we want with them)
    for (int match_num = 0;  match_num < total_matches;  ++match_num) {
        struct match_obj match = all_matches[match_num];
        for (int i = 0;  i < match.count;  ++i) {
            printf("Match %d.%d: %s\n", match_num, i, match.matches[i]);
        }
    }

    // 4. Free the allocations - array of string-pointers here, created-strings in get_next_match()
     for (int match_num = 0;  match_num < MAX_TOTAL_MATCHES;  ++match_num) {
        match_obj_free(all_matches + match_num);
    }

}
```